# Slow performance using canvas line animations

Tags: html, performance, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm using *requestAnimationFrame* for animatin some lines in a website. The thing is that this animation increases the use of the processor significally and the animation is not smooth.

[image: CPU Use]

Sometimes is **more than 70% of CPU usage.**

I don't know if is the animation or the reposition of lines

```
function animateline() {
  reqAnimFrame =
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

  reqAnimFrame(animateline);

  x += speed;

  if (x <= 0 || x >= 475) {
    speed = -speed;
}
  reposition();
}
```

The full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/a4cNp/46/

The fullscreen version of the page -> http://jsfiddle.net/a4cNp/46/show/light/

Thanks in advance.

Added a Firefox Profiler image. Maybe it is usefull to locate the problem but, I still don't know how to solve it.

[image: Firefox Profiler]

Comment: Firefox has a really nice Profiler built into its web developer tools.  It can tell you what code the browser spends the most time in.

Comment: first thing : do not polyfill inside the loop, but just once, when your site launches. Show the reposition code please.

Comment: do you test on fast (>120Hz) screen ?

Comment: I'm to check the firefox thing. The full code is in the jsfiddle link. I'm watching this on a 2009 iMac... I don't know if this is a fast screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GameAlchemist says, put your polyfill once near the top of your code instead of inside your animation.  Your animation loop gets called many times per second, so minimize the amount of work that loop has to do.

**One observation: You're doing way too many jQuery selections.**

First, cache the jQuery objects you want to reposition along with their dimensions:

Do this once near the top of your code:

```
var $area1=$("#area1");
var $area2=$("#area2");
var $area3=$("#area3");
...
var area1Width=$area1.width();
var area1Height=$area1.height();
...
```

Then use those cached values on your often-called code (like reposition):

```
function reposition(){

    $area2.css("left", area1Width+40);

    ....
```

Comment: i fully agree with you markE (how surprising ! :-)) i would add that there are a LOT of code redudancy going on, so @George you should 1) write up a function as soon as you see the same code twice, and 2) store within an array every similar objects (expl area1,2,3...). You will both divide your code base by ten -so many advantages- and allow the interpreter to optimize much more easily.